# Why does the High Table use such outdated tech?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

In *John Wick: Chapter 3 – Parabellum*, the process of someone being issued the status *excommunicado* is shown. Throughout multiple scenes we see the High Table "logistics department" using:

- Switchboard operators
- Chalkboards to keep track of bounties
- Typewriters
- Extremely outdated computers
- Old fashion intercom systems for records requests

**Why do they use such outdated tech?**

[image]

Comment: And how do they find all these tattooed and pierced young folks that are willing to do shady mafia-level business in 60's style office clothes?

Comment: It's still "advanced" in comparison with Bowery King's pigeons!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect it's combination of two things

1. Older tech is harder to track/copy/leak, so helps keep the information away from law enforcement (not that I really recall seeing any in the movies, other than the guy that visited John's house in the first movie)
2. An aesthetic choice by the director/writer, it gives the world a unique look and style.

Comment: And then just don't make them like they used to...